# r count instances where variables x and y are equal and place in table

Tags: r

I have the following code

```
length(which(tor$TorL==1& tor$SID==351))
length(which(tor$TorL==1 & tor$SID==352))

## The result of this is as follows

[1] 3843
[1] 223
```

The lines of code give me the count of TorL when SID==xxx.
TorL is a binary variable of a low value
SID goes from 351 to 358, I am only showing 351.

My second code query is

```
length(which(tor$TorH==1 & tor$SID==351))
length(which(tor$TorH==1 & tor$SID==352))

## Results from above

[1] 155
[1] 96
```

TorH is a binary variable of a high value

I would like to able to do this count as above and place the results in a table, something like as follows, as I would like to do a correlation on the results.

```
SID   TorL   TorH
351   3843   223
352   155    96
```

Thanks
[image: Sample table]

Comment: Can you please edit your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to help?

Comment: I have added a sample table.

Comment: `aggregate(.~SID, tor, sum)` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
df <- data.frame(SID = sample(c(351, 352, 353), 30, replace = T),
                 TorL = sample(c(0,1), 30, replace = T),
                 TorR = sample(c(0,1), 30 , replace = T))

df %>% group_by(SID) %>% summarise_at(vars(TorL, TorR), sum) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 × 3
    SID  TorL  TorR
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   351     6     8
2   352     3     6
3   353     6     6
```

Comment: When I try and run this code I get the following error  Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: You should load tidyverse: `library(tidyverse)`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, playing around a little with asafpr answer

```
{r}
torlh <- df %>% group_by(SID)%>%
  summarise(ltor = sum(TorL), htor = sum(TorH))
torlh
```